# gdalwarp won't run with "cubic" resampling method

Tags: gdal, gdalwarp, resampling

I am having an issue with running the *gdalwarp* command from command prompt.
Basically I have a [raster WGS84 file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3pbwtxg54rnvnqd/vesuvius2_wgs84.tif?dl=0/), which I would like to reproject to spatial reference which is using the Azimuthal Equidistant projection, but with *"cubic"* resampling method.
This is the syntax that I am using:

```
"C:/gdalwin32-1.4.1/bin/gdalwarp.exe" -s_srs EPSG:4326 -t_srs "+proj=aeqd +datum=WGS84 +lat_0=40.81266 +lon_0=14.414252" -r cubic -of GTiff "C:/vesuvius_wgs84.tif" "C:/vesuvius_cubic_aeqd.tif"
```

([40.81266, 14.414252](https://www.google.rs/maps/place/40%C2%B048'45.6%22N+14%C2%B024'51.3%22E/@40.8054039,14.3671706,12z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x0:0x0?hl=en) is the center of the raster)

For some reason when I press "Enter", the *vesuvius_cubic_aeqd.tif* file is not created, but instead I get the following text printed on my command prompt:

```
gdalwarp [--help-general] [--formats]
    [-s_srs srs_def] [-t_srs srs_def] [-to "NAME=VALUE"]
    [-order n | -tps | -rpc | -geoloc] [-et err_threshold]
    [-refine_gcps tolerance [minimum_gcps]]
    [-te xmin ymin xmax ymax] [-te_srs srs_def]
    [-tr xres yres] [-tap] [-ts width height]
    [-ovr level|AUTO|AUTO-n|NONE] [-wo "NAME=VALUE"] [-ot Byte/Int16/...] [-wt Byte/Int16]
    [-srcnodata "value [value...]"] [-dstnodata "value [value...]"] -dstalpha
    [-r resampling_method] [-wm memory_in_mb] [-multi] [-q]
    [-cutline datasource] [-cl layer] [-cwhere expression]
    [-csql statement] [-cblend dist_in_pixels] [-crop_to_cutline]
    [-of format] [-co "NAME=VALUE"]* [-overwrite]
    [-nomd] [-cvmd meta_conflict_value] [-setci] [-oo NAME=VALUE]*
    [-doo NAME=VALUE]*
    srcfile* dstfile
```

What is the problem?

Interestingly, if I remove the *"-r cubic"* part like so:

```
"C:/gdalwin32-1.4.1/bin/gdalwarp.exe" -s_srs EPSG:4326 -t_srs "+proj=aeqd +datum=WGS84 +lat_0=40.81266 +lon_0=14.414252" -of GTiff "C:/vesuvius_wgs84.tif" "C:/vesuvius_cubic_aeqd.tif"
```

everything works correctly, and *vesuvius_cubic_aeqd.tif* file is created.
To make it more strange, I tried replacing the *"-r cubic"* with *"-r bilinear"* or *"-r average"*, but again neither of these worked. I also tried, removing the *"-of GTiff"*, and that did not work either.

What am I doing wrong in the upper gdalwarp command syntax?

Comment: I just ran it on my OSGeo4W 64-bit based GDAL, and it worked with "-r cubic". Have you tried a different installation?

Comment: Thank you for the help @MikkelLydholmRasmussen.
Indeed I tried a newer version: gdal 1.6 (http://download.osgeo.org/gdal/win32/1.6/gdalwin32exe160.zip) after your suggestion, and it worked!
How can I label your reply as the one that solved the problem?

Comment: Don't update from eight years old version to a six and a half years old version. Get a maintained 1.11 or 2.0 version from http://www.gisinternals.com/ or through OSGeo4W.

Comment: Thank for the reply. The reason why I am downloading from: http://download.osgeo.org/gdal/win32/ is because it contains all the necessary files in their respective folders. When I download the Gisinternals.com .zip file, I need to somehow copy some of the content from one folder to the other, in order for the "gdalwarp.exe" to work. Most of the time I do not know which files I need to copy.
Can you recommend the link at OSGeo4W?

Comment: I do not understand. I just unzip the gisinternals zip file and run the sdkshell.bat (with hideoci) from the main directory and everything works for me.

Comment: What does the "with hideoci" mean?

Comment: You will see a short explaining message when you'll try. Parameter de-activates Oracle driver which can otherwise throw some error messages.

Comment: Thank you for the reply @user30184. I am reluctant to try to execute it, as this may interfere with some of gdal environment variables I set through gdal C# bindings.
So once I run the "sdkshell.bat", AND press Enter, a message will appear stating that hideoci deactivated Oracle driver? And that is it? After that, the command prompt window can be closed (I am using Windows os)?

Comment: If you double click sdkshell.bat you will on the screen `Setting environment for using the GDAL and MapServer tools.
WARNING: If you encounter problems with missing oci libraries then type:
  SDKShell hideoci`. So type `SDKShell hideoci` It will re-run the batch file with parameter "hideoci". Open the bat with text editor and you can see what happens then. It begins with `if "%2"=="hideoci" goto hideoci`.